# Problem compiling liblas on OSX 10.8

Tags: mac, osx, liblas

I'm trying to compile liblas since I can't find any Mac executables out there(?). I have OSX 10.8 and XCode 4.6.3.

Since I'm not a programmer I get really confused when I follow the instructions on [liplas.org](http://www.liblas.org/compilation.html#using-xcode-on-os-x) . In those instructions older version of XCode is being used so with the new XCode I can't find anything..

I get stuck [here](http://www.liblas.org/compilation.html#set-default-command-for-xcode)

And if I just skip all the steps and try compile in XCode I just get this message:

> make -f
>   /Users/oskarlin/Downloads/libLAS-1.7.0b2/xcode/CMakeScripts/ReRunCMake.make
>   make[1](http://www.liblas.org/compilation.html#using-xcode-on-os-x): *** No rule to make target
>   `/Users/oskarlin/Downloads/libLAS-1.7.0b2/xcode/CMakeFiles/2.8.10/CMakeCCompiler.cmake',
>   needed by`CMakeFiles/cmake.check_cache'.  Stop. make: ***
>   [/Users/oskarlin/Downloads/libLAS-1.7.0b2/xcode/CMakeFiles/ZERO_CHECK]
>   Error 2 Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2

Has anyone here complied it for Mac and could perhaps give me an updated instruction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using OSX, you should try the [Home Brew](http://brew.sh/) from which you can easily get libLas by doing the following command in your terminal window.

`brew install liblas`

Comment: Thank you! Perhaps their website should be updated...?